# Calculating critical D statistic for KS test with one sample of data and three fitting distributions

Tags: goodness-of-fit, curve-fitting, kolmogorov-smirnov-test, scipy

So, I have a bunch of data, and I am after determining which distribution function fits that data the best. So, I define three distribution functions, one Gaussian and two non-Gaussian, and fit them to the data using SciPy.CurveFit in python. Now, I calculate the D-statistic for the data with all the three fitted distributions by performing the KS test, and by making CDF of data and calculating the max absolute difference between CDF data points and CDF fitted functions. So, I have three D-statistic values, and I say that the least D-statistic value function fits the data the best. However, I need to define the critical D-statistic, to interpret this properly, and I cannot find how to calculate the D-statistic for made-up functions in the KS test. I just want to know which fitted function fits the data the best. Is comparing D-statistic for the three fits even the right approach? If not, what should I do, and which tests should I perform instead? Thanks [image: The image shows my data (in red) and three fitting functions I use to fit it.]